# OleDbCommand, WHERE don't care

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

With an Access table (CustomersTable) and two fields (CustomerID, CustomerName) ... field#2 contains "Zap":

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT  CustomerID, CompanyName   FROM CustomersTable   WHERE  CompanyName =  @p1";
command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "Zap";
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Works fine.

Changing the parameters value to "Za*" finds nothing.  What is used for "don't care"?

Comment: The wild card character for any match is `%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "Zap" is not equal to "Za"

You nee to use `Like` operator something like this:-

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT  CustomerID, CompanyName   FROM CustomersTable   WHERE  CompanyName LIKE @p1";
command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "%Za%";
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use a LIKE command:

```
SELECT  CustomerID, CompanyName   FROM CustomersTable   WHERE  CompanyName LIKE  'Za%'
```